# iOS App not correctly showing on device

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm learning to create an App and I have made a UIViewController with two buttons. This works correctly on both simulator and real device. Now I have made the background color red in IB and it only works on simulator. Even adding a new UILabel doesn't show up on a device only on a simulator.

I'm not getting an error (at least not that I know/see). What can be the problem?

---

It appears that when I set the background color in code. It works on both device and simulator. So my guess it has something todo with the storyboard not rebuilding or something?

Comment: Can you add pictures?

Comment: It is a red square with two buttons in it. Not much to see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possible solutions for this problem:

1. Try to clean your build: Look for "Product > Clean" in the XCode Menu.
   Cleaning is always an issue in XCode and you should use it rather often.
2. Try to delete the current version from your device and built+run it again
3. If those two don't help, find your "DerivedData" folder and delete it manually.
4. Restart XCode (Yes this can have an effect)
5. remove the Storyboard from your XCode project (don't delete it) and then add it again.

Hope that helps,
Sebastian

Comment: No luck, but will take the advice with me ;)

Comment: Ok then try to delete the app from your device and then try again.

Comment: Also tried. But It is 'fixed' now. I removed the storyboard and added it again from trash? Now It works as expected??

Comment: Sometimes restarting XCode can also help or deleting the DerivedData folder manually!

Comment: Sebastian if you could add the things said in the comments: - deleting DerivedData and deleting storyboard and re adding and stop xcode. I can give you the correct answer

Comment: There you go. Hope this is of help to others out there as well.